# javascript mouse up android

Tags: javascript, android

Just want the position of the mouse on mouseup,

This works on a desktop but not an android browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var two = 0;

    window.onmouseup = gogo;
    function gogo(eve){
        two = eve.clientY;
        document.write(two);    
    }
</script>
```

I've tried several alternatives but haven't got the right answer.

Any clues?

This edit:  I notice a delay on answering this post even though there are a lot of views. Am wondering what it is that makes this question so elusive.

Comment: do you have a mouse connected to the android device?

Comment: On android, you write *touch* event handlers instead of *mouse* event handlers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Touch_events

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hover in a mobile browser...

It depends on the requirement...

For **Example..**

1. you have a dropdown menu list. when you hover on menu, submenu
   appears -> here the menu can also have a link..

   ```
        - Menu (a href="a.html")
            - submenu1 (a href="b.html")
            - submenu2 (a href="b.html")
            - submenu3 (a href="b.html")
   ```

For this you cannot use dropdown because on **clicking menu** ****it redirects..****

**WHAT YOU CAN DO IS**

use alternatives like **javascript** or some **CSS**

> For **Javascript** write **script** like on **Menu click** invoke some
>   script and **check if it is a mobile browser** and handle whether to
>   show **submenu div** or not

---->   http://jsfiddle.net/pDp4T/11/  <-------